# Why does a string index based array appear sorted in angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I created the following:

```
interface IMap {
[name: string]: string;
}

var map: IMap = {};
map["S"] = "s";
map["C"] = "c";
map["D"] = "d";
```

When I go over an ng-repeat in angular, it prints them in this order c, d, s instead of s, c, d. Why is it being sorted?

Comment: take a look at my answer, but i will suggest you to use array in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular will check the type of collection you would like to iterate, below is the snippet from source code, as you can see `collectionKeys.sort()` is sorted by alphanumeric ASC.
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L333

```
if (isArrayLike(collection)) {
  collectionKeys = collection;
  trackByIdFn = trackByIdExpFn || trackByIdArrayFn;
} else {
  trackByIdFn = trackByIdExpFn || trackByIdObjFn;
  // if object, extract keys, sort them and use to determine order of iteration over obj props
  collectionKeys = [];
  for (var itemKey in collection) {
    if (collection.hasOwnProperty(itemKey) && itemKey.charAt(0) != '$') {
      collectionKeys.push(itemKey);
    }
  }
  collectionKeys.sort();
}
```

if you want it ordered as you put but still using object, you can create another array to keep the keys and ng-repeat on it. pseudocode below

```
scope.map = {S: 's', C: 'c', D: 'd'};
scope.mapKey = ['S', 'C', 'D'];

<div ng-repeat="key in mapKey">
    {{map[key]}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`Objects` are not ordered in JavaScript. If you want order, you need to use an `array`.

I don't know exactly how to do that with TypeScript, but I imagine something like this:

```
var map: IMap = [];
```

Angular by default is sorting your `object literal` alphabetically because it doesn't have an order.

Think of the object literal like a dictionary.

Comment: I don't want it ordered, I want it printed as I added it s, c, d but ng-repeat is printing it as c,d,s

Comment: @bb2 That means you want it ordered. If you use an `object`, the order you add elements to it means nothing. I'm not talking about sorting. (In Angular's case, it looks to be sorted alphabetical, but it will be random depending on the implementation).